# How to get a file into variable, by starting perl script with windows context menu

Tags: windows, shell, contextmenu

I've recently created a Word to SharePoint Page converter.
The `converter.pl` was made into an `.exe` so everyone in our company can use it without perl installed.
It currently has a GUI, where you can add `.doc` and `.docx` files via file explorer.

I've rewrote the code and added a context menu entry for .doc and .docx files which starts `converter.pl`.

Now my question is, instead of adding several documents via the GUI, I want to accomplish a one click (in context menu) which starts the converter.pl with the currently selected file.docx as an input file.

```
my $input = "the file+its path I selected via Windows context menu";
```

How would I do this?

Comment: AFAIK this is done via a registry entry. I don't know exactly how, but a first web search for "windows add application to context menu" looked promising.

Comment: I think you should better ask this on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com), or possibly even on [sharepoint.se]. It's not really a Perl question. You'd make your Perl program read filenames from it's command line, and get Windows to put all the file names into the command line. For that, it doesn't matter what your program is written in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `.reg` file (adjust the paths as needed)

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.docx\shell\CONVERT\command]
@="c:\\Perl\\bin\\perl.exe c:\\Perl\\converter.pl \"%1\""
```

When your perl script starts, you'll have your `.docx` file name in the `$ARGV[0]` variable.